# Deploying war file on Vesta CP

Tags: java, ftp, war, cpanel, vps

I am doing this for the first time. I have a VPS server with Vesta CP installed on it. I did the following -

1. Created a new Web Domain.
2. It automatically created entries in DNS
3. I setup FTP user for myself.
4. I am able to connect to ftp using Fileszilla.
5. In filezilla, I can see public_html folder (but NOT .htaccess)
6. Created WAR file from eclipse for my application.
7. Uploaded my war inside public_html.
8. tried - http://myserver_ip/MenuBook/HomePageServlet - in browser. It
   said 404 Page not found. (MenuBook is the ContextRoot of my web
   application)

Can someone please explain what else do I have to do to make this work. I read that you have to modify .htaccess file too, here - https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Deploy+Java+Applications

But I can not see any .htaccess file through ftp.

Please help. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must install web server that support java servlets like tomcat or glassfish ...  vestacp by default has no just webservers you must install it your self
you can check this link it may help 
https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6977